# Is Hibernate and my DB connected?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My server started without any errors. When I request for get user by id, I am not getting results. My DB credentials are correct and I have set show_sql to true. Still I don't see any call to DB. **Is my DB connected or not?**

**Edit**

**How to test Connection?**

Config:

**in dao.xml:**

```
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="classpath:application.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**In userdaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Long, User> implements UserDao {
@Override
public User getUser(String id) {
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId", id));
    return (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```